# Why did MYCIN fail?

Tags: expert-systems

I've been reading about expert systems and started reading about MYCIN.

I was astonished to find that MYCIN diagnosed patients better than the infectious diseases physicians.

http://www.aaaipress.org/Classic/Buchanan/Buchanan33.pdf

Since, it had such a good success rate, why did it fail?